# Why does China have desert greening programs but Australia and the USA don't?

Tags: united-states, china, australia

China has undertaken a lot of desert greening projects.

- [The Great Green Wall of China](https://widerimage.reuters.com/story/the-great-green-wall-chinas-farmers-push-back-the-desert-one-tree-at-a-time)

[image]

Why does China do that and other countries like the USA and Australia don't?

Comment: Could you link to some of these lots of desert greening projects? What success have they had so far?

Comment: Have you ever flown over the western US? You'll see lots of patches of green in what would otherwise be desert or extremely arid grasslands if you do. There are debates galore regarding whether or not those chunks of green (many of them with federal government assistance) in the desert are a good idea.

Comment: see also the "dust bowl" that the US has mostly managed to tame. Otoh, it looks like there are still sand storm in Beijing.

Comment: Not sure about Australia, but for the US [a similar thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Plains_Shelterbelt) was done back in the 1930's-1940's and is still maintained today (along with a lot more farms than there were back then). Maybe instead of "why don't they do this", it'd be better to ask "do they have/need any similar programs"?

Comment: In the US such programs will often be done by private businesses and landowners, while in China it is up to the government. Are you asking about government programs specifically, or any programs?